# how to create tc server instance

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tcserver

I have already installed Pivotal tc Server Integration for Eclipse by this link
[Drag  to install](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pivotal-tc-server-integration-eclipse)

But I can't create server instance. where is it default directory ? Pls help.
[image: Eclipse screencut]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only installed the tcServer integration without installing tcServer. That's your problem.